# How do I check that this function is analytic using the derivatives?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, analytic-functions

I have the following problem.

We define $\Omega=\Bbb{C}\setminus \{x:x\in (-\infty 0]\}$. For $z=x+iy\in \Omega$ we define the curve $\gamma_z$ going first from $1$ to $1+iy$ and then from $1+iy$ to $z$. Then we define $$f(z)=\int_{\gamma_z} \frac{1}{w}dw$$ for $z\in \Omega$. I want to calculate the derivative of $f$ to show that $f$ is analytic.

Now I have decomposed the curve into two linear curves and then written the integral over $\gamma_z$ as the integral over these two curves. I obtained the following curves:
$$\gamma_{z1}(t)=(1+iy)t+(1-t)=1+tiy$$ and $$\gamma_{z2}(t)=(x+iy)t+(1-t)(1+iy)=t(x-1)+1+iy$$ for $t\in [0,1]$. Then I calculated the following integrals $$\int_{\gamma_{z1}}\frac{1}{w}dw=\left(\frac{1}{iy}+1\right) \log(1+iy)$$ and $$\int_{\gamma_{z2}} \frac{1}{w}dw=\log(x+iy)-\log(1+iy)$$ It follows $$\int_{\gamma_z}\frac{1}{w}dw=\frac{1}{iy}\log(1+iy)+\log(x+iy)$$.

But is this even true up to this point? Now I thought I'd just derive these complex functions and I'd be done but I'm not quite sure if I'm allowed to do it this way.

Could someone help me here?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You do not need to calculate $f(z)$ explicitly. Just show that $f'(z)={1\over z}.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc thank you for your answer. But this isn't the main theorem of analysis for complex functions we use here?

Comment: If it is complex differentiable once, at one point, it is infinitely differentiable and analytic in a neighbourhood of that point

Comment: @FShrike sorry we haven't had this statement. Is there a way to compute the differential of $f$ and get $f'(z)=1/z$ ad Ryszard Szwarc said?

Comment: The curve is not important as long as it is contained in the region, i.e. doesn't touch the nonpositive real half line. If you are aware of the complex version of the fundamental theorem of calculus you are done.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc so we had the following: Let $f$ on a night of a curve $\gamma[a,b]$. Then $\int_\gamma f'(z)dz=f(\gamma(a))-f(\gamma(b))$ but I don't think this is what we want

Comment: That's nearly exactly what we want, except the result is equal $f(\gamma(b))-f(\gamma(a))$ Here the role of $f'$ is played by $1/z $

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Ah sorry that was a typing error. But shouldn't I compute $f'(z)=\left(\int_{\gamma_z}\frac{1}{w}dw\right)'$ so I mean is this equal to $\int_{\gamma_z} \left(\frac{1}{w}\right)'dw$?

Comment: No, you should prove that $$f'(z)={d\over dz}\int\limits_{\gamma_z}{1\over w}\,dw={1\over z}$$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Ah and then I can swap $\frac{d}{dz}$ and the integral and apply my formula?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135271/discussion-between-ryszard-szwarc-and-aprozz).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are going to show that $f'(z_0)={1\over z_0}$ for $z_0\notin (-\infty,0].$
To this end we need to prove
$$\lim_{z\to z_0}{f(z)-f(z_0)\over z-z_0}={1\over z_0}$$
Let $d={\rm dist}(z_0,(-\infty, 0])=\displaystyle \min_{t\le 0}|z_0-t|.$ Assume $|z-z_0|<{d\over 2}.$ Then $z\notin (-\infty, 0].$ Intuitively, it means that if $z$ is close to $z_0,$ then $z$ does not belong to $(-\infty, 0].$
Observe  (by drawing a picture) that the line segment $[z_0,z]$ connecting $z_0$ and $z$ does not intersect the half-line $(-\infty, 0].$ More precisely, the distance of every point $w$ in this segment to $(-\infty, 0]$ is greater than ${d\over 2}.$

While calculating the derivative we can restrict to $z$ close to $z_0,$ for example to $|z-z_0|<{d\over 2}.$ Let $z=x+iy$ and $z_0=x_0+iy_0.$
By definition
$$f(z)-f(z_0)=\int\limits_{\gamma_z}{1\over w}\,dw -\int\limits_{\gamma_{z_0}}{1\over w}\,dw  =\int\limits_{\gamma_{z_0,z}}{1\over w}\,dw$$
where $\gamma_{z_0,z}$ consists of three line segments: the first one from $z_0$ to $1+iy_0,$ the second one from $1+iy_0$ to $1+iy$ and the third one  from $1+iy$ to $z.$ As the function ${1\over w}$ is holomorphic in the domain, the integrals over $\gamma_{z_0,z}$ and the line segment  $[z_0,z]$ are equal, as the region between them does not intersect $(-\infty,0]$ (again the picture could be helpful). Therefore
$$f(z)-f(z_0)=\int\limits_{[z_0,z]}{1\over w}\,dw$$
As $z$ is an antiderivative of $1$ we get
$$z-z_0=\int\limits_{[z_0,z]}\,dw$$ hence
$${1\over z_0}={1\over z-z_0}\int\limits_{[z_0,z]}{1\over z_0}\,dw$$
Furthermore
$${f(z)-f(z_0)\over z-z_0}-{1\over z_0}={1\over z-z_0}\int\limits_{[z_0,z]}\left [{1\over w}-{1\over z_0}\right ]\,dw$$
We obtain
$$\left |{f(z)-f(z_0)\over z-z_0}-{1\over z_0}\right |\le {1\over |z-z_0|} l([z_0,z])\max_{w\in [z_0,z]}{|w-z_0| \over |w|\,|z_0|}$$
Observe that the length $l([z_0,z])$ is equal $|z-z_0|$ and that $|w-z_0|\le |z-z_0|$ for $w\in [z_0,z].$  Moreover as the distance of $w$ to $(-\infty, 0]$ is greater than ${d\over 2},$ we get $|w|\ge {d\over 2}.$ Summarizing we obtain
$$ \left |{f(z)-f(z_0)\over z-z_0}-{1\over z_0}\right |\le {2|z-z_0|\over d|z_0|}$$
Therefore $f'(z)={1\over z}$ for any $z\notin (-\infty, 0].$ Hence the function $f(z)$ is holomorphic.

**Remark**

1. A similar reasoning can be performed replacing the function $z^{-1}$ by any holomorphic function in order to show that it admits antiderivative in an appriopriate region.
2. I intentionally haven't used the fact that $f(z)=\log z, $ (the main branch of the complex logarithm) as afterwards one has to show (also a known fact) that $\log z$ is holomorphic in the described region. Moreover the complex logarithm can be actually defined in terms of the integral by choosing $\gamma_z$ consisting of the line from $1$ to $|z|$ and part of the circle with radius $|z|,$ from $|z|$ to $z.$ In this way we get $\log z=\log|z|+i{\rm Arg }\,z.$

Comment: I have considered your proof and remarked that it is similar to the one for the Morera theorem. I did not understand everything from your proof but I understood the one from Morera. Thus I wanted to redo this exercise with the idea we used in Morera's Proof. would it be possible to upload that one so that you can have a look?

Comment: The Morera theorem states that if the integrals along the boundary of every triangle is $0,$ the integrated function is holomorphic. If you can apply that to $\int\limits_{\gamma_z}{1\over w}\,dw$ it is fine. But it requires change of the order of integrals.

Comment: we had a version using rectangles and not triangles

Comment: I will upload my solution if I'm done

Comment: Sorry I can't upload pictures, I don't know why. Since I have some pictures it would be hard to write everything. So would it be possible to write you an email with the solution?

Comment: You can upload your solution through the chat we have opened yesterday.

Comment: Oh perfect I didn't noticed that so I will upload it now. Could you maybe take a look at it?

Comment: I uploaded it. Thank you if you take a look

Answer (score 1):

I believe your first integral is in error. In general, given any branch of a logarithm and any contour, $\gamma$, within a simply connected region of it's domain, that starts at $z_1$ and ends at $z_2$, you have

$$ \int_\gamma \frac{1}{w} dw = \log(z_2) - \log(z_1) $$

Likewise, as expected your mutual point should cancel out. This is because the path is irrelevant when you are integrating a differentiable function. This should look like the fundamental theorem of calculus.

$$ \int_{\gamma_1} \frac{1}{w} dw = \log(1+yi) - \log(1)$$

$$ \int_{\gamma_2} \frac{1}{w} dw = \log(x+yi) - \log(1+yi)$$

therefore,

$$ \int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{w} dw = \log(x+yi) - \log(1)$$

Even if you did $u$-substitution and did the contour integrals directly, you would still get the same answers.

Comment: But then I can derive $log(x+yi)$ right? And get $\frac{1}{z}$

Comment: Yes, directly $\lim_{w\to z} \frac{log(w)-log(z)}{w-z} = \frac{1}{z}$ everywhere you have defined your logarithm. Although proving that directly is typically considered quite tedious. Many opt to prove backwards, like showing $\frac{d}{dz} \int_{z_0}^z \frac{1}{w} dw= \frac{1}{z}$.  Or another way is to show that inverse of differentiable functions are always differentiable and simply prove that $e^{log(z)} = z$ everywhere the logarithm is defined (making it an inverse of a differentiable function).

Comment: But do I need to compute it explicitly or would it be enough to say that $f'(z)=(\log(z))'$. Because then we have a complex derivative at each $z$, so $f$ is holomorphic and thus also analytic.

Comment: would this also be enough?

Comment: Many things in mathematics are circular and I don't know where you are at in your studies. Have you already established that the function $f(z) = \log(z) = \ln|z| +\arg(z)i$ is  differentiable, with derivative $\frac{1}{z}$. If so, then yes $\int_1^z \frac{1}{w}dw$ is a differentiable function. If your class is defining $f(z) = \log(z) = \int_1^z \frac{1}{w} dw$ and asking you to prove that is differentiable. Then, no, you are probably being expected to provide a proof using something else already shown to be true (inverse differentiability; derivatives of integrals, etc.).

Comment: Hmm okey so I need to compute it but there I get some problems. So using the competitions form your answer I get that $f'(z)=(\log(z))'$ Now I need to compute $(\log(z))'$ I know that the inverse of an analytic function is analytic and hence the  inverse of differentiable functions are always differentiable. So since $e^z$ is differentiable also $log(z)$ is differentiable. But then I don't see how to get to $1/z$

Comment: (inverse differentiable theorem) If $A$ and $B$ are open subset of $\mathbb{C}$, and $f:A\to B$ is one-to-one and onto and differentiable. Then the function $g:B\to A$ defined by $g(z)=w$ where $f(w)=z$, will also be differentiable and it's derivative will be $g'(z) = \frac{1}{f'(g(z))}$.

Comment: This means that since $\exp(z)$ is differentiable, then the derivative of $\log(z)$ is $(\log(z))' = \frac{1}{\exp'(\log(z))} = \frac{1}{z}$.

Comment: Ah okey no we haven't seen this but I can also use that $\log(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(1-z)^n}{n}$ and then use the forumla for the differential of the sum right?

Comment: Again, is that how you defined $\log(z)$ in your class? If so, then absolutely. If not, how was $\log(z)$ defined in your class?

Comment: so we have defined the logarithm as follows: it is a function $f:\{z\in \Bbb{C}: |z-1|<1\}\rightarrow \Bbb{C}$ such that $e^{f(z)}=z$ but then this somehow doesn't work since we need it on the whole $\omega$ not only on $\{z\in \Bbb{C}: |z-1|<1\}$ right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135277/discussion-between-bobby-ocean-and-aprozz).

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is circular. To compute the integral $\int_\gamma \frac 1 w dw$ you use the fact that the function $\frac 1 w$ has a (complex!)  antiderivative which you correctly denote by $\log$. But if you use this fact, you essentially invoke what are supposed to prove.

In fact, it is well-known that on the sliced plane $\Omega$ there exist infinitely many branches of the complex logarithm, any two differing by an integral multiple of $2 \pi i$. Using any branch and any differentiable path $\gamma : [a, b] \to \Omega$ you get
$$\int_\gamma \frac 1 w dw = \int_a^b \frac{1}{\gamma(t)}\gamma'(t)dt =  \int_a^b \log'(\gamma(t))dt = \log(b) - \log(a) .$$
You may take the branch with $\log(1) = 0$ and get
$$\int_{\gamma_{z1}} \frac 1 w dw =  \log(1+iy) $$
which shows that you made a mistake in your computation. Similarly you get
$$\int_{\gamma_{z2}} \frac 1 w dw = \lg(x+iy) - \log(1+iy) =\log(z) - \log(1+iy)$$
and therefore
$$\int_{\gamma_{z}} \frac 1 w dw = \log(z) .$$

A non-circular proof has been given by Ryszard Szwarc.